# Is there something wrong with my try catch zero division?

Tags: c++

I tried to make simple program to catch and error by making function that divided an int to zero but i don't see the error neither the correct output

```cpp
#include <iostream>

constexpr double division(int a, int b){
    if(b == 0)
        throw "Cannot be divides by  zero";
    return (a / b);
}


int main(){
    int x {50};
    int y {0};
    int z {0};
    z = x / y;
    try{
        z = division(x ,y);
        std::cout << z << std::endl;
    }catch (const char* msg) {
     std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
>  C:\Users\Tungki\Desktop\c>g++ jj.cc
>  C:\Users\Tungki\Desktop\c>a
>  C:\Users\Tungki\Desktop\c>
> ```

As you can see nothing happens here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing

```
int x {50};
int y {0};
int z {0};
z = x / y; <<<<<<<<<<< divide by 0
```

the code after is not executed (undefined behavior), probably you do not wanted to divide by zero using '/' but using your function ;-)

putting `z = x / y;` in comment you get your expected behavior :

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr double division(int a, int b){
    if(b == 0)
        throw "Cannot be divides by  zero";
    return (a / b);
}


int main(){
    int x {50};
    int y {0};
    int z {0};
    // z = x / y;
    try{
        z = division(x ,y);
        std::cout << z << std::endl;
    }catch (const char* msg) {
     std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra d.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Cannot be divides by  zero
```

Comment: It's *undefined behavior* which precedes the well-defined `division` call. It still may appear to "work".

Comment: @LogicStuff yes, in my case `z = x/ y;` writes `Exception en point flottant` then stop the execution (sorry for french message ^^)

Comment: The English version is `Floating poing exception` (the message for `SIGFPE`).

Comment: @melpomene hehe yes sure, I put the French version I get mainly for joke, the translation is funny because in French we use _comma_ (in French _virgule_) rather than _point_, so _exception en virgule flottante_